# Database design: how to investigate raw data and model it into an existing database?

Tags: sql-server, database, data-warehouse, database-design

As a database developers, what is the best way to investigate new raw data for database when you have to model this data into an existing database? I mean a situation where you get raw data for example in text files and you don't have any description about the data types or column lengths in that file. I'm looking for tools and best practices to do this investigation. Is there available some pre-defined tools for this in SQL Server?

Edit: I'm talking about the technical side of this process, e.g. how to see if data in a columns has to be mapped into SQL Server table as tinyint, int or bigint...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me that you are looking for a data-profiling tool. Your title "... *to model* ..." is a bit misleading.

Take a look at a few options:

- **[SSIS data profiling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc952923.aspx)** task
- **[Talend](http://www.talend.com/products-data-quality/talend-open-profiler.php)**
- **[Data Cleaner](http://datacleaner.eobjects.org/)**

Answer (score 3):

There are no tools that will tell you what data means.

You need to talk to the owners of the data, understand the meaning of it and when you are comfortable with your understanding, you can model your database and create your ETL process.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not talking about what the data means, I'm talking about the technical side to this process, how to get info about the data to decide e.g. data types for columns (tinyint, int, bigint) etc.

Comment: @jrara - This is not a technical exercise. You need to understand what the data mean before you can decide the right data type for it, or you risk modelling incorrectly and making a database that is not fit for purpose.

Comment: @Oded - Yes, you are right, but I would like to know what methods people have to investigate raw data.

Comment: @jrara - They go to the people that own the data and ask them.

Comment: @Oded - Yes, that's the usual way but unfortunately I have seen cases where there is some legacy system with no sensible documentation. In these cases one has to investigate data and create those mappings

Comment: @jrara - In those cases, one has to investigate the _applications_ that use the data and talk to the people who _use_ these applications in order to extract meaning. Unless the database has no users, in which case, why does it exist?

Comment: @Oded - There is not always an "application" behind these things. Data can come from excel sheets or some other spreadsheet "applications". I those cases data can be "wild" and you have to investigate what kind of data the spreadsheet has.

Comment: @jrara - And who created these spreadsheets? No one? And who uses them? Again, no one?

Comment: @Oded - I got your point already, but you don't seem to get mine. Well, anyway, you are right, maybe we are done with this conversation.

Comment: @jrara - I get your point, but you can extract meaning out of raw data, not with tools, not automatically or mechanically. You need a person in order to transform data to information.